# Why is email rejected due to a specific URL in the message body?

Tags: email, url

This is bizarre. I am trying to send an email containing this link:
http://newslamp.com/post/158516/home-made-robot-doing-a-perfect-quadruple-backflip

This is going out through my ISP (RCN), to stmp.rcn.com. I live in the Boston area, but I'm emailing from British Columbia, Canada, using the OS X mail client. When I try sending, the error message says:

```
Sending the message content to the server failed.

Select a different outgoing mail server from the list below 
or click Try Later to leave the message in your Outbox until 
it can be sent.
```

- If I change the email message by adding text: fail
- If I modify the url after the domain name: fail
- If I change the "http" to "ahttp" (for example): fail
- If I remove "http://": fail
- If I change the domain name: email goes out

It's not an intermittent problem -- I've tried this about seven times by now, and it is completely reproducible.

From Thunderbird running on Ubuntu 12.04, email goes out regardless of the domain name, but email containing the link to the correct domain name does not get delivered. Email with the incorrect domain name does get delivered.

What would explain this behavior? How can I figure out where the rejection is happening (mail client? mail server? Some server between here and there?)

Comment: What email address is the email sent from?

Comment: From my own domain, as I've been doing for many years. What I can't understand is why behavior seems to depend on message content.

Comment: Has anything recently been added to server? Software? Spam filter? Have you tried sending from a mobile to see if it is the desktop?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I have my own domain, and email I send appears to come from my domain. However, I use RCNs smtp service. So my own server is not involved at all in outgoing email.

Comment: Right so that means it possibly could be RCNs strict email filter and also could be the MX records set for your domain name as this should be included in you SPF record to authenticate but wouldn't make to much difference unless you had set it to hard fail

Answer (score 1):

Yes by the looks of this link http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r28323974-E-Mail-RCN-Spam-Mail-filter-  rcn has a very aggressive spam filtering system so you would be better turning this off or configuring your mx records and using your servers mail system